# infinite recursion on a function receiving a rvalue and calling to the lvalue version

Tags: c++

Basically, I have the following situation

```
   template <class GT>
   GT create_graph(size_t n)
   {
      GT ret;
      // some stuf on ret

      return ret;
    }

    template <class GT>
    void test(const GT & g)
    {
      // processing on g
    }

    template <class GT>
    void test(GT && g)
    {
      test(g); // call to const GT& (lvalue version)
    }

    int main()
    {
      test(create_graph<Graph>(100));
      test(create_graph<SGraph>(100));
      test(create_graph<AGraph>(100));
    }
```

All the three types (`Graph, SGraph, AGraph`) have copy and move constructors and assignment operators.

The rvalue version is temporal. Afterward I will write a specialized version. But in the meantime I call the lvalue version.

According to my understanding, the first line (and the following ones), creates an rvalue object (by calling to `create_graph()`). This rvalue is passed to the rvalue version of `test()` which call to lvalue version of `test()` (please correct me if this is not exactly true).

Now, for a reason that I can not understand, the rvalue version of `test()` falls in infinite recursion. Apparently, it deals `g`as a rvalue. As I see, the parameter `g` (without performing move o forward) is a lvalue.

I tested with two different compilers and in both my code falls in infinite recursion. So, I conclude that I have done something wrong, either by my lack of understanding or because something happens to the instance of `GT` that makes the compiler interpret `g` as an rvalue.

So, if anyone can propose an explanation to clarify me what is happening, then I will be very grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your temporary objects are *not* `const`, so you call the universal-reference function overload recursively. Use this instead:

```
template <class GT>
void test(GT && g)
{
  test(static_cast<std::remove_reference_t<GT> const&>(g));
}
```

---

Another option suggested by Scott Meyers is to use a dispatch:

```
template <class GT>
void test(GT &&g, std::true_type)
{
     //implementation for l-value references
}

template <class GT>
void test(GT &&g, std::false_type)
{
     //implementation for r-value references
}
```

and then call those from the original function

```
template <class GT>
void test(GT &&g)
{
     test(std::forward<GT>(g), std::is_lvalue_reference<GT>());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tested it and works fine. A little longer than my previously answered fix, but it seems more general

Answer (score 2):

```
template <class GT>
void test(GT&& g) // universal reference
{
    test(g); // equivalent to test<GT&>(g)
}
```

calls itself as `g` is a non const lvalue.

As you only want to forward to the other overload and the rvalue can be bind to const reference, you may omit completely `template <class GT> void test(GT&& g)` and keep only `template <class GT> void test(const GT& g)`.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I changed the return value of `create_graph()` to `const GT` and now the flow is `test(rvalue)` then `test(lvalue)`, which solves my problem for now. However, I'm still not sure I understand; I have to study more

Comment: @lrleon: davidhigh's solution is better than returning const object. Or even better, remove the overload which take universal reference.

Comment: Yes @Jarod42. I adopted davidhigh's solution. Thanks again

Comment: @lrleon: Note that in your case, the best solution seems to omit completely the universal reference overload.